# Docker cannot bind to ipv4 while using host network

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-network

I have a program which deploys on docker needs link to host network.So I run this commmand

```
docker run -d --network host demoProgram
```

The exposed port is 80 .
I found that it only bind ipv6 after entering the command

```
netstat -tnlp
```

The result of the command was

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      680/rpcbind
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1044/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      1097/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      680/rpcbind
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2052/dotnet
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1044/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::33060                :::*                    LISTEN      1097/mysqld
```

What should I do to make the container bind ipv4?

Comment: Once you've disabled Docker networking like this (you should almost never need to) it's entirely up to the application.  Can you edit the question to include the parts of the application source code that set up the network listener?

Comment: It is a initial website application of net core,and i haven't change a word of it  . @DavidMaze